# Uncaught TypeError: e.replace is not a function in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm try to show modal when click the day in calendar. when click the modal is show correctly. But all of older event is lost and I've receive error

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.replace is not a function
at nt (fullcalendar.min.js:16)
at _ (fullcalendar.min.js:17)
at O (fullcalendar.min.js:17)
at lt.E [as renderEvents] (fullcalendar.min.js:16)
at R (fullcalendar.min.js:16)
at fullcalendar.min.js:16
```

and I found a new error when close and click to show modal again

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.replace is not a function
at nt (fullcalendar.min.js:16)
at _ (fullcalendar.min.js:17)
at O (fullcalendar.min.js:17)
at lt.E [as renderEvents] (fullcalendar.min.js:16)
at Z (fullcalendar.min.js:16)
at K (fullcalendar.min.js:16)
at u.O [as renderEvent] (fullcalendar.min.js:16)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (fullcalendar.min.js:17)
at Function.each (jquery.min.js:186)
at e.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:63)
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="CaseSurvey/calendarSurvey/calendarSurvey.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-title">
                <h3>
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    Calendar
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box-content nopadding">
                <div class="calendar2" id="calendar"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="addEventModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add Event Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <label for="eventTitle">Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="eventTitle" id="eventTitle" /><br>
                <label for="eventStart">Start Date</label>
                <input type="text" name="eventStart" id="eventStart" /><br>
                <label for="eventEnd">End Date</label>
                <input type="text" name="eventEnd" id="eventEnd" /><br>
                <input type="radio" id="allday" name="allday" value="1">Half Day
                <input type="radio" id="allday" name="allday" value="2">All Day
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value=""/>
            </div>     
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="calendarModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
                <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body"> </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

calendarSurvey.js:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();


    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
    {
    header:
    {
        left: 'today',
        center: 'prev,title,next ',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },

    defaultView: 'month',

    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,

    select: function(start, end, allDay)
    {
        $('#addEventModal').modal();
        if (title)
        {
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end,
                    allDay: allDay
                },
                true 
            );
        }
        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
    editable: true,
    events: [
        {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, 1)
        },
        {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
            end: new Date(y, m, d-2),
            textColor:'orchid',
            color:'peachpuff'
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
            allDay: false
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
            allDay: false
        },
        {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
            color: 'plum',
            allDay: false
        },
        {
            title: 'Lunch',
            start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
            end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
            allDay: false
        },
        {
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
            end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
            color: 'salmon',
            allDay: false
        },
        {
            title: 'Click for Google',
            start: new Date(y, m, 28),
            end: new Date(y, m, 29),
            url: 'http://google.com/'
        }
    ],
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {


        $('#modalTitle').html(calEvent.title);
        $('#modalBody').html(view.name);
        $('#eventUrl').attr('href',calEvent.url);
        $('#calendarModal').modal();


    }
});
});
```

and I include fullcalendar.min.js in index.php

Comment: I'm puzzled by your "select" function. Where does "title" come from? Why are you not waiting for the user to actually type details into the modal before you try to render the resulting event? I suspect that everything in that function after the call to `.modal()` actually ought to be in a function that runs when the user clicks the "save" button in the modal.

Comment: Calling `.modal()` doesn't pause the execution of your script, it simply displays a form on the page. Even if it did, you have to code it to select the value of "title" from the form elements. I would guess that this logical error is the root of your problem. Lastly, why does your "addEvent" form ask for start/end dates when the user has already indicated this by selecting the area on the form? And the you ask for selection of half day / all Day which would ignore any time selection? Your form does not make much sense.

Comment: OK, I got it. The line I'm set 'title' it lost. Thank you ADyson